# Excluding identical returns from ACCESS query when names are equal

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, select, max

In MS ACCESS, I have a table containing names and dates for when a persons yearly exam expires. This exam is valid for 12 months, so the next exam is typically done before all 12 months have expired.
Table, called "Exam", looks like this (in the real table names are unique):

```
ID   Name   Dateexp
1    Peter  30/07/2020
2    john   10/09/2020
3    Bob    11/10/2019
4    Peter  25/06/2021
```

I have a query that shows the persons with a "valid" exam. I looks like this:

```
SELECT Name As Name, Dateexp As Expiry FROM Overall WHERE Dateexp > now();
```

It returns:

```
Name     Expiry
Peter    30/07/2020
John     10/09/2020
Peter    25/06/2021
```

Problem is that "Peter" has done a new exam thereby extending his expiry date from 30/07/2020 to 25/06/21 and I only want the latest one to be shown.
Query should return:

```
Name     Expiry
Peter    25/06/2021
John     10/09/2020
```

I am truly lost - does anyone have an idea as to how this can be solved?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use max and having clause:

```
Select name, max(dateexp) as dateexp
from overall
Group by name
Having max(dateexp) > now()
```

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you can just use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select name, max(dateexp) as expiry 
from overall 
group by name
having max(dateexp) > now();
```

This filters on names whose *latest* expiry date is in the future.

Comment: You both solved it simultaneously.-) It works perfectly - thank you very very much.

Comment: Voted you up for the extra explanations